# Trouble reading directional derivative proof

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I'm reading Vector Calculus from http://mecmath.net/. This is a free PDF book for students of Calculus III. In section 2.4 (page 78) it introduces the directional derivative and theorem 2.2:

[image: Theorem 2.2 from Vector Calculus book]

So far so good and I get the intuition. I am having trouble following the proof of the theorem though. Please see following picture:

[image]

I understand the first equality; a partial w.r.t. $y$ is being taken so $x$ is being held constant at $a + hv_1$ therefore it can be considered the derivative of a function $g(y) = f(a+hv_1,y)$.

I'm confused where $\alpha$ goes after the 2nd equals sign. I'm confused that $g\prime$ is claimed to be equal to some difference quotient and not the limit of the difference quotient. If anyone could talk me through what's going on here I'd be grateful.

Comment: Mean value theorem!

Comment: I glazed over that bit in the proof. Was a while ago since I did the MVT. Looking again now, thanks...

Comment: Read the equation encircled in red from right to left, then everything is obvious.

Comment: I believe I understand it now. The MVT says the average slope matches the slope of the tangent line in at least one place on the interval. So the circled equation is only true for some values of $\alpha$. Turns out we don't need to know what the $\alpha$'s are as later in the proof $\alpha$ (and $\beta$ which is similarly introduced) vanish in the limit as $h \rightarrow 0$. I've now followed the proof step by step until the end. My intuition as to what's happening at every step (i.e. geometrically) faded a bit, but should I be concerned at that given that I understood each step?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a very over complicated way of proving $D_{\underline{u}}f(x_{0},y_{0}) = af_{x}(x_{0},y_{0})+ bf_{y}(x_{0},y_{0})$ where $(a,b)$ is the unit vector associated with $\underline{u}$ i.e. $(a,b)$ =  $\frac{\underline{u}}{\left \| \underline{u}  \right \|}$. We will prove this in a way that is much easier to understand.

To do this we do define $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $g(h) = f(x_{0} +ah,y_{0} +bh)$.

So, from our difference quotient we get

$g'(0)$ = $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{g(h) - g(0)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(x_{0} + ah,y_{0} + bh) - f(x_{0},y_{0})} {h} = D_{u}f(x_{0},y_{0})$

But, using the chain rule we get $g'(h) = \frac{\mathrm{d} g}{\mathrm{d} h} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} h} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} h}$ and we note that $x = x_{0} + ah$, $y = y_{0} + bh$ so $\frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} h} = a $ and $\frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} h} = b$

Then we have $g'(h) = a \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + b \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ and so we evaluate this at $h = 0 \implies (x,y) = (x_{0}, y_{0})$ and equate our different expressions to get $D_{\underline{u}}f(x_{0},y_{0}) = a \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x_{0}, y_{0}) + b \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_{0}, y_{0})$ which is what we wanted.

Comment: Can you expand on how $\underline{u} = (a,b) = \frac{(x_{0},y_{0})}{\left \| (x_{0},y_{0})  \right \|}$? Isn't $\underline{u}$ independent of the direction "origin to $(x_{0},y_{0})$"? My understanding is we're taking the derivative at point $(x_{0},y_{0})$ in the direction of $\underline{u}$ and $\underline{u}$ is unlikely to be parallel to the line segment from origin to $(x_{0},y_{0})$.

Comment: I have no idea why I wrote that, bit of a brain fart, I'll edit it to write what I actually meant